# $E[g(X,Y)|Y]=\int_\Omega g(X(\omega),Y)dP(\omega)$ for random vector $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

I know that, if $X$ is independent of $Y$, it holds

$$E[g(X,Y)|Y]=\int_\Omega g(X(\omega),Y)dP(\omega)$$

Does this apply, if $Y$ is not only one random variable, but let's say a vector of random variables? Can $X$ be a vector of random variables, too?

A book or reference for that would be great!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Proof is same wtheher you have one random variable $Y$ or a collection of $Y$'s.

Comment: Actually, I could not find any book yet, which is proving this result. Do you have a reference for the proof? Or does it just follow from another result? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it maybe, that $g(\cdot,Y)$ is a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable function and by the law of the unconscious statistician? And if yes, why is that so? I am a bit confused how I should see that $g(\cdot,Y)$ is a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.